# How to inject command to application shell inside docker container?

Tags: bash, docker, shell

When running

```
docker exec mycontainer -it  -- /usr/bin/myapp
```

myapp shell is opened

```
myapp>
```

How to inject command to that prompt scriptable way so that it would be the same like giving command manually?

```
myapp>mycommand
```

Comment: Is `/usr/bin/myapp` only a shell, or it can receive commands from the cli, will the following work: `/usr/bin/myapp mycommand` if you are running `myapp` locally?

Comment: Generally you wouldn't do this at all, any more than you'd get an interactive shell on a local Nginx server or your Web browser.  Interact with the container process through its published network interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
docker exec -i mycontainer /usr/bin/myapp << EOF
mycommand
EOF
```